# The Solr server could not be reached. Further data is therefore unavailable

Tags: solr, drupal-7

I installed solr 5.4.0, enabled modules search_api and search_api_solr on my drupal site. When I'm trying to add search server it's adding but

> CONNECTION:   The Solr server could not be reached. Further data is
>   therefore unavailable.

The Solr Server URI is(without space)

> SOLR SERVER URI:  http: //drupal_learning:8983/solr

But when I'm trying to click that link it sends me to

> http://drupal_learning:8983/solr/#overlay-context=

And browser gives me an error:

> 404 Not Found Get #overlay-context=

But if I try to go to http://drupal_learning:8983/solr by typing it in addressline it's OK.
Do I need to change somehow Solr Server URI or do smth else?

Comment: Used xdebug but still can't understand, where wrong url has been constructed

Comment: Do you see the request in the Solr log when it attempts to set up the connection? Do the Drupal configuration require the collection name as well? (`/solr/<collection name>` as the path)

Comment: There is nothing in logs about it. I don't know if the Drupal configuration require the collection name. What I need to do to know?

Comment: Problem with links is a result of drupal overlay module in drupal core. When I disabled the module the problem has gone.

Comment: The problem with connection is because of ping URL. There is no URL http://drupal_learning:8983/solr/admin/ping on my Solr Admin but that URL is required.

Comment: Is it ok that ping button in core menu is <a rel="/solr/drupal_learning/admin/ping"><span>Ping</span></a>? What does it do?

Comment: If that's what its trying to do, it probably does not want the core name in the URL. The ping URL is usually `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/ping`. Try it in your browser.

Comment: **HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /solr/admin/ping. Reason:

    Not Found**

Comment: Does "ping" inside the Solr Admin interface work? (it pings /solr/corename/admin/ping) .. is the Solr interface available at all, and does it contain the core you're looking for?

Comment: "ping" doesn't work. interface is available. It contains the core.

Comment: `http://localhost:8983/solr/drupal_learning/admin/ping` shows me `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<response>
<str name="status">OK</str>
</response>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got it! I needed to change Solr path in http://drupal_learning/admin/config/search/search_api/server/drupal_learning/edit from

> /solr

to

> /solr/drupal_learning

Comment: I didn't understand you, MatsLindh, when you were asking me about that path. Thank you)